# Installer dealing with users copying files to system paths

Tags: installation

How do you deal with upgrade issues caused by customers copying files from the install location to other folders? - be it system folders or any other on the path.

Is it a failure in your new installer if there is a mess? 
How far do you go to identify potential messes?
Do you check the path for any other copy of files with matching names?

Comment: Why are your users doing that?

Comment: I don't know why they would do that just at the moment, I don't have direct access to ask.

Comment: And what can you do? Repair or Upgrade should restore/update the files at their original locations. If users copied or moved files, you can't detect it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what installation engine you are using. So there are two cases:

1. MSI packages (Windows Installer) can use [major upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369786%28VS.85%29.aspx?ppud=4). So a new version simply uninstalls the old one and performs a full installation. Whatever was moved by the user will simply remain on his machine.
2. Non-MSI package (proprietary engines) use multiple approaches. Some update the existing installation, others try to use a major upgrade mechanism.

The conclusion would be that you can ignore these cases if you use a good installer engine.